# Using Variables in SQL Queries on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of IDs for which I want to extract other information from a sql table. This is my python 3 code:

```
ID=['A1','A3','B45','F44']

for i in ID:

    sqlquery="select Name, Age from TABLE where id=%s"
    cursor.execute(sqlquery,i)
```

I get this error upon running the code:

```
vertica_python.errors.Error: Argument 'parameters' must be dict or tuple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument must be a tuple. Do it like this:

```
ID=['A1','A3','B45','F44']

for i in ID:

    sqlquery="select Name, Age from TABLE where id=%s"
    cursor.execute(sqlquery,(i,))
```

Note: the `(i,)` treats `i` as single element tuple